# How do i find confidence interval for $P(a<X<b)$, with $a,b$ known and $X\sim \text{Exp}(\theta)\,$?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

> How do i find confidence interval for $P(a<X<b)$, with $a,b$ known and $X\sim \text{Exp}(\theta)\,$? $(x_1,x_2,…,x_n)$ are given, where the $x_i$ are iid exponential random variables.

My initial idea was to find $$P(a<X<b)=P(X<b)-P(X<a)=e^{-\theta a}-e^{-\theta b}$$ and then isolate $\theta$, so i can transform the usual confidence interval for $\theta$.

Comment: Your question needs additional details.  What does the sample look like?  Are you given $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are iid exponential random variables?

Comment: If I were about to post an answer to this, I would explain that I will assume that data are the values of $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\text{i.i.d.}\operatorname{Exponential},$ but that should be stated in the problem if that is what was intended.

Comment: A transformation such as you suggest should work except that (1) possibly there is no closed form, so numerical methods would be needed, and (2) whether it is the shorts possible confidence interval at the level that it's at is a question that will bear examination.

Comment: @heropup $(x_1,x_2,…,x_n)$ are given, where the $x_i$ are iid exponential random variables!.
My second ideia was to create $\mathbb{I}\{a<X<b\}\sim \text{bernoulli}(\theta=P(a<X<b))$ where $\mathbb{I}\{A\}$ is the indicator variable for A , and find a confidence interval for $\theta$.